# passing websocket messages from django consumers.py to html, then respond back to backend

Tags: django, websocket, ws

The problem i'm having is

1. The only way i can find to pass messages from consumers.py which recieves the message to index.html where its needed is with this line.

```
async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name, {"type": "chat_message", "message": message}
        )
```

this sends the message to index.html AND back to my backend... i dont want it to bounce the message back to my backend.

2. how can i send a response back to my backend from index.html because i need to send info on what the user has entered into an in?

here is an example of how the system currently works

[how websockets currently work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8R31.png)

and heres how i want them to work

[how i want websockets to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbJyb.png)

how can i stop bouncing the message back to my backend and still pass the message onto my html, then respond from my html back to my backend?

################

below is the code

js in my index html

```
const colorSocket = new WebSocket(
    "ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws/endpoint/chat/"
);

colorSocket.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Connected! (" + this.readyState + ")");
};

colorSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
    let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log(data.message);
    //  etc...........
    }
```

consumers.py

```
import json
import random
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        print('connected')
        self.room_name = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["room_name"]
        self.room_group_name = "chat_%s" % self.room_name

        print(f"Connected to {self.room_group_name}")

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):

        print("Recived ="+str(text_data))

        json_data = json.loads(text_data)
        message = json_data["message"]

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name, {"type": "chat_message", "message": message}
        )


        from . import views
        print(views.stuff)
        try:
            message = "logged in as ==="+str(views.stuff['username'])
        except:
            message = "not logged in "

        self.send_response("Response from Django: " + message)   # i want this response back to my external script

    def send_response(self, message):
        # Send the response message to the WebSocket
        self.send(json.dumps({'message2': message}))

######

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["message"]
        print("dis function")
        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message}))  #    i want this to send messages to my frontend, but not back to my external script. it does both
```